# Sorting and Filtering

Tags: javascript

i got the following array of objects

```
[
{
  xType: "M",
  pets: [
   {
    name: "kitty",
    type: "Cat"
   },
   {
    name: "Doggy",
    type: "Dog"
   }
  ]
},
{
  xType: "F",
  pets: [
   {
    name: "kitty",
    type: "Cat"
   }
  ]
},
{
  xType: "M",
  pets: null
},
{
  xType: "M",
  pets: [
   {
    name: "Akitty",
    type: "Cat"
  },
  {
    name: "Bkitty",
    type: "Cat"
  },
  {
    name: "Doggy",
    type: "Dog"
  },
  {
    name: "CKitty",
    type: "Cat"
  }
 ]
}
]
```

How do i use lodash to get all the cats and display them in alphabetic order under the xType so the result will be like

How do i basically generate the array below from the one that i gave at the start?

```
[
 M : [ {
   name: 'AKitty',
   name: 'BKitty',
   name: 'CKitty',
   name: 'Kitty'
  }
 ],
 F: [ 
   {
   name: kitty
    }
  ]
]
```

is it supposed to be filter and has or what ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a lodash implementation:

```
var result = _(data)
  .groupBy('xType') // group each item by xType
  .mapValues(function(value) { // map each key value
    return _(value)
      .flatMap('pets') // get all pets
      .filter({ type: 'Cat' }) // Only get cats
      .map('name') // get the names of all pets
      .sort() // sort names
      .value();
  }).value();
```

```js
var data = [{
  xType: "M",
  pets: [{
    name: "kitty",
    type: "Cat"
  }, {
    name: "Doggy",
    type: "Dog"
  }]
}, {
  xType: "F",
  pets: [{
    name: "kitty",
    type: "Cat"
  }]
}, {
  xType: "M",
  pets: null
}, {
  xType: "M",
  pets: [{
    name: "Akitty",
    type: "Cat"
  }, {
    name: "Bkitty",
    type: "Cat"
  }, {
    name: "Doggy",
    type: "Dog"
  }, {
    name: "CKitty",
    type: "Cat"
  }]
}];

var result = _(data)
  .groupBy('xType') // group each item by xType
  .mapValues(function(value) { // map each key value
    return _(value)
      .flatMap('pets') // get all pets
      .filter({ type: 'Cat' }) // Only get cats
      .map('name') // get the names of all pets
      .sort() // sort names
      .value();
  }).value();


document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Interesting i was still fighting with _.groupBy how do i get all the Cats only though?

Comment: The result of the above for some reason shows `Object {M: LodashWrapper, F: LodashWrapper}` with no data do you know why that may be? That is in the console.log

Answer (score 1):

In plain Javascript, you could use this proposal with an outer loop and an inner loop for the pets. Then test and assign the names.

I changed the data structure for the result to one without syntax problems.

```js
var array = [{ xType: "M", pets: [{ name: "kitty", type: "Cat" }, { name: "Doggy", type: "Dog" }] }, { xType: "F", pets: [{ name: "kitty", type: "Cat" }] }, { xType: "M", pets: null }, { xType: "M", pets: [{ name: "Akitty", type: "Cat" }, { name: "Bkitty", type: "Cat" }, { name: "Doggy", type: "Dog" }, { name: "CKitty", type: "Cat" }] }],
    grouped = {};

array.forEach(function (a) {
    grouped[a.xType] = grouped[a.xType] || [];
    Array.isArray(a.pets) && a.pets.forEach(function (b) {
        b.type === 'Cat' && grouped[a.xType].push(b.name);
    });
});

Object.keys(grouped).forEach(function (k) {
    grouped[k].sort();
});

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: It works well but does not sort the array M . Thanks though i will try to recreate this in lodash

Comment: Cool, will see ho to do it in lodash